# enable ipv6 for interface in windows

Tags: .net, windows, ipv6

How do I programmatically enable IPv6 for given interface? Can be netsh, WMI or whatever that can be called from C# program. Equivalent to clicking on a checkbox in interface properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (Windows 8+):

```
static void SetIPv6State(Guid interfaceId, bool state)
{
    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\StandardCimv2");
    var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetAdapterBindingSettingData");
    var methodName = state ? "Enable" : "Disable";
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    using (var bindings = searcher.Get())
    {
        var binding = bindings.Cast<ManagementObject>().Single(obj => (string)obj["InstanceID"] == interfaceId.ToString("B").ToUpper() + "::ms_tcpip6");
        var parameters = binding.GetMethodParameters(methodName);
        binding.InvokeMethod(methodName, parameters, new InvokeMethodOptions());
    }
}
```

Windows 7 requires C++ code.